# i am not able to clear the code below given using throwable concept in java

Tags: java

```
public StackException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
}
```

in the above code what StackException does after the method is invoked

Comment: It invokes constructor in `Exception` class which you probably extended

Comment: The question is not clear and out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that the constructor `StackException` is just passing the `message` and `cause` to its super class. And so, the regarding super class constructor is invoked.

Don't be confused by Exceptions, it is just like any other Java inheritance.

Now, you just need to see what is the the super class of `StackException` and see what its constructor is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here super class  constructor is invoked through stack exception.
Don't relate here throw able  with errors and exception.